# Zabbix JMX Item key syntax for CompositeData With List<Object>

Tags: jmx, zabbix

I have created jmx agent which generates custom data as attribute and returned as composite data type when viewed in jconsole.

The original datatype is ArrayList. How would I construct the jmx item key in zabbix.

```
jmx[com.example:Type=Hello,fruits.apple.weight]
```

How would I do if I need to access an array of objects.
Any ideas or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, accessing array or lists is currently not supported in Zabbix, but there is a feature request for that: [ZBXNEXT-1570](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1570).